# Variable isn't being incremented in lisp loop

Tags: lisp, conditional-statements, common-lisp

I'm writing a program that will read information from a file, but when I try to read the information for some reason my count variable isn't being incremented.

```
(defun fill-lib()
   (with-open-file (s-stream "/Users/David/Desktop/CS/CS_408/LISP/Books.txt"
                           :direction :input)
      (loop
        (cond((> count 1) (return "Library filled")))
          (setf (aref *lib* count)
                (make-instance 'book :title (read s-stream)
                  :author (read s-stream) 
                  :genre (read s-stream)))
          (setq count (+ count 1)))))
```

I have a feeling its because I'm not using the loop properly but I'm not entirely sure how I could fix that.

Comment: 1) Don't use undeclared variables (like count).  2) What is `(> count 1)` supposed to do the first time, when there's no value assigned to count? 3) You'd probably want `incf` rather than `(setq count (+ count 1))`.  4) You haven't shown any error message or anything like that.  What makes you think that "[your] count variable isn't being incremented"?  It seems to me like you'd get some other errors than that, and probably some compiler warnings too (even before you (try to) run your code).

Comment: as what?  I think your comment is missing something

Comment: Sorry about that I had the variable count initialized as: (setq count 0) I'm beginning to suspect that I might only be reading the first line of my file for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have implemented the loop, only one book will ever be added to `*lib*`. This is because you are explicitly terminating the loop when `count` exceeds 1, i.e. after the first book entry has been read from the input file:

```
  (cond((> count 1) (return "Library filled")))
```

Instead of checking a counter, I guess I would add a small function whose sole purpose is to read one book entry from a stream, and that function would indicate to the caller when there is no input left. (Or you could exit from the loop when a `book-title` with a `nil` value is detected. The best approach depends on the structure of the input data, and on the level of robustness you are after, of course.)

Here is a rough variation of your code, using the approach of adding a function which is dedicated to reading a single book entry from the input:

```
(defstruct book 
  (title nil)
  (author nil)
  (genre nil))

(defun read-book(s)
  (make-book :title (read-line s nil :eof) 
             :author (read-line s nil :eof)
             :genre (read-line s nil :eof)))

(defun fill-lib ()
  (let ((lib ()))
    (with-open-file (s "/tmp/Books.txt" :direction :input)
      (loop for book = (read-book s)
            until (eq (book-title book) :eof) do
          (push book lib)))
    lib))

(print (fill-lib))
```